# How to pass environment variable to .yml file through command line?

Tags: powershell, yaml, command-prompt

I need to pass environment variable to .yml file through command line.

Please suggest!

Comment: There is no such concept as environment variable expansion in YAML. If such a thing is implemented it is at the level of the application reading the YAML file. What application is doing so?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the append operator if you're Unix based. The `>>` operator will append the data to the end of the file.

EX: `echo "env_variable" >> example.yml`

Comment: I am using Window.

Comment: This is going to make your YAML file **invalid** in all practical cases except for maybe a handful (toplevel literal scalar string without indentation and no end-of-document marker). Apart from that this adds a string not an environment variable.